# fadeIn fadeout in the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
success:function(result) {
  $('#priceDiv').fadeOut(3000);
  $('#priceDiv').fadeIn(3000,function(){
    document.getElementById("priceDiv").innerHTML = result;
  });
```

In this code I want the old data from `priceDiv` to slowly fade out and the new data slowly fade in, in the `priceDiv`.

The result holds the new data from an ajax request.

I have already succeeded slowly fade out with old data but the fade in show the old data again and when it's finish the new data show with no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use callback method of `fadeOut` to set data and the fadeIn

```
$('#priceDiv').fadeOut(3000, function(){
    //Set new Data
    document.getElementById("priceDiv").innerHTML = result;

    //Fade in with new data
    $('#priceDiv').fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off of what @Satpal said, try the following.

```
$('#priceDiv').fadeOut(3000, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html(result);
    $this.fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Save off the element in a variable to prevent jQuery from having to re-traverse the DOM on each call. It's more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(result) {   
 $('#priceDiv').fadeOut(3000, function(){
        $(this).html(result);
        $(this).fadeIn(3000);
    });
}
```